# How to pass object out of vue instance to instance data

Tags: vue.js

I have app.js file:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
import Home from './components/Home'

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    render: h => h(Home)
});
```

Then in my Home.vue I have:

```
<template>
    <div>

        <app-footer v-bind:mylinks="mylinks"></app-footer>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Links from './home/Link.vue'

    export default {
        components: {
            'app-footer': Links
        },
        data() {
            return {
                mylinks: links
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Then in my Link.vue I have:

```
<template>
    <footer>
        <nav>
            <ul class="menu-items">
                <li v-for="link in mylinks"><a :href="link.url" class="menu-item">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </footer>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['mylinks']
    };
</script>
```

Before  and script for app.js I have:

```
<script>
        var links = {
            [title: 'home', url: '{{ route("home") }}'],
            [title: 'about', url: '{{ route("about") }}'],
            [title: 'privacy', url: '{{ route("privacy") }}'],
            [title: 'terms', url: '{{ route("terms") }}'],
            [title: 'contact', url: '{{ route("contact") }}'],
            [title: 'login', url: '{{ route("login") }}']
        };
    </script>
```

How can I pass my links object to Home.vue mylinks ?

I can't push it to that object after app.js script because it is not in app.data but in Home.vue data?

Answer (score 0):

do you have the same footer everywhere on your website? if yes, you don't need to pass your links to the footer component. You can simply import js file with links object into it.

create `footer.links.js' and put this into it:

```
const route = function() { ... }
const links = {
  [title: 'home', url: '{{ route("home") }}'],
  [title: 'about', url: '{{ route("about") }}'],
  [title: 'privacy', url: '{{ route("privacy") }}'],
  [title: 'terms', url: '{{ route("terms") }}'],
  [title: 'contact', url: '{{ route("contact") }}'],
  [title: 'login', url: '{{ route("login") }}']
}
export links
```

then in your footer component:

```
<script>
  import { links } from '~/footer.links.js'
  ...  
</script>
```